# ios-charts PieChart's label (legends) missing

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9, ios-charts

I am trying to implement pie chart from ios-charts library everything is working great, however I am missing legends from the graph -

[image]

Here is my code -

```
// This is the delegate method for creating data for chart
        func offDaysDidLoaded(controller: DataModel,chartArray:[PFObject]) {


                let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "MMM"
                dataDict = [:]
                for od in chartArray {
                    let date = od["Date"] as! NSDate
                    let month = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
                    if self.dateDict.indexForKey(month) != nil {
                        self.dateDict[month]! += 1.0
                    }else{
                        self.dateDict.updateValue(1.0, forKey: month)
                    }
                }
                let dataPointArray = Array(dateDict.keys)
                let valuesArray = Array(dateDict.values)
                pieChartView.data = nil
                pieChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                setChart(dataPointArray, values: valuesArray)
            }


func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {

        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Months")

    let pieChartData = PieChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: pieChartDataSet)
    pieChartData.setDrawValues(false)
    pieChartView.data = pieChartData
    pieChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: NSTimeInterval(5))

    var colors: [UIColor] = []

    for _ in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))

        let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
        colors.append(color)
    }

    pieChartDataSet.colors = colors

}
```

I have seen similar issue in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970306/piechart-for-ios-charts-broken-in-swift-2-0) and build and run, pie chart used in the issue also doesn't show any legends below the chart. Any help or pointer would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you changed anything? It seems like the legends is showing up, but masked by something. You can debug the legend first. BTW, try to reproduce this with ChartsDemo and your data. If ChartsDemo works fine, then you def changed something

Comment: I haven't changed anything and the legends are not getting masked by something because when i print "pieChartView.legend.labels", I get empty array [] which means the legends data is missing that confuses me because other data from same data source or data set is available i.e. months and dates. Why only legend labels missing? I have provided the method I am using for supplying the data on the actual question.

Comment: try reproduce with ChartsDemo

Comment: I tried to re-produce it with charts Demo data as below - months = `["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]
        
setChart(months, values: unitsSold)` It works fine with static array data but fails when i get the data dynamically.

Comment: what you mean dynamicly?

Comment: It means when i am populating the data based on runtime value and not the static array, the legends are missing. But when i Pass the static array as in above mentioned comment it works fine. I also tried to print the legends by - pieChartView.legend and it was empty.

Comment: I guess you need to file this bug on github. provide data code within ChartsDemo

Comment: @AppsWise If the legend works for static data than there must be a logic failure in your dynamic data. When you print/inspect `values` inside `setChart` what does the data actaully look like?

Comment: Thanks for the response this is what i get when i print the dataEntries filled dynamically I don't see any error in this `[ChartDataEntry, xIndex: 0, value 4.0, ChartDataEntry, xIndex: 1, value 2.0, ChartDataEntry, xIndex: 2, value 4.0, ChartDataEntry, xIndex: 3, value 4.0, ChartDataEntry, xIndex: 4, value 2.0, ChartDataEntry, xIndex: 5, value 2.0, ChartDataEntry, xIndex: 6, value 4.0, ChartDataEntry, xIndex: 7, value 8.0, ChartDataEntry, xIndex: 8, value 2.0, ChartDataEntry, xIndex: 9, value 2.0]`

Comment: I have raised an issue in git hub for same here [ios charts legends missing](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/issues/518)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally this issue is resolved it wasn't the bug. Please find the detailed solution [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/issues/518).

Answer (score 2):

I just did try ChatsDemo with

`legend.position = ChartLegendPositionBelowChartLeft;`

works fine. So either your data problem, or you modified something. You don't show how you setup x values. Give more details or debug on your own. Should be easy